# Where is the data (xml?) stored when a report is deployed?

Tags: reporting-services

When I haved developed a Reporting Services report and deployed it to the server, where is the actual report stored? I'm guessing the SQL-database, but what table and in what format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it is typically stored in the ReportServer database in the dbo.Catalog table.

Here is a Query which will get you the XML for the report.  I have used this to feed a PowerShell script which replaces all of the current footers with a standardized footer for the company.

```
SELECT  f.[Name] as Module,
        r.[Name],
        CAST(CAST(r.[Content] AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS reportXML
FROM  dbo.[Catalog] r WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN  dbo.[Catalog] f WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.ParentID = f.ItemID
                                   and f.[Type] = 1
                                   and f.path like '[your_path]%'
WHERE   r.[Type] = 2
and r.path like '[your_path]%'

ORDER BY r.[name]
```

This will give you an XML column you can click-on and the XML will be displayed for you.